# Netty 4.1.17 leak detector w/o detail

Tags: memory-leaks, netty

Trying to upgrade a code to use Netty 4.1.17, a leak error is sometimes raised by `ResourceLeakDetector`:

```
17:18:12.589 ERROR [s.n.u.ResourceLeakDetector] :: LEAK: ByteBuf.release() was not called before it's garbage-collected. See http://netty.io/wiki/reference-counted-objects.html for more information.
Recent access records: 
[info] My debug
```

After `Recent access records:` there is no detail about where the leak has been detected, so that's hard to figure out the cause.

The detection level is set to PARANOID using `-Dio.netty.leakDetection.level=paranoid` (the property is found at test runtime).

Any idea how to get more info?

Comment: And this not happened before ?

Comment: The ref counting is new w/ Netty 4.x

Comment: So you upgraded from 3.x to 4.x ?

Comment: Yes, to 4.1.17.Final

Comment: It should have a stacktrace included as well in the logs... That said I am sure you missed to call `release()` once you are done consuming the `ByteBuf` or anything that implement `ByteBufHolder`.

Comment: I'm only allocating non-`direct` `Unpooled` buffer, so that's rather related to channel handler, were `release()` is called on the last inbound handler. There is no stack trace (even if the new ref counting behaviour is quite error prone when migrating legacy code).

Comment: hmm there should be a stack trace. Are you sure you call release() on the last ChannelInboundHandler you have in the pipeline one channelRead(...) completes ?

Comment: Seems the logging level used by the leak detector is not coherent/unified as it prints the error message partially (message w/o cause)

Comment: Can you share the project that gives the error ? I never saw the logging messed up :(